# While exporting the ASPTemplateField column data of grid to EXCEL PDF and CSV the data is not displaying

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Actually i am gridview in that i used one TemplateField column its displaying data in browser
when exporting that grid to EXCEl, PDF and CSV the data is not displaying for that column , how to fix this issue . Thank you

HERE the .asp code

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvmacroManagement" runat="server" Font-Size="Small" Height="40px" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" OnPageIndexChanging="gvmacroManagement_PageIndexChanging"
                                BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" CssClass="mGrid">


                                <Columns>

                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="ID" ItemStyle-Width="50" Visible="false" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="Physician Name" ItemStyle-Width="50" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Hospital" HeaderText="Hospital Name" ItemStyle-Width="50" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="MacroTitle" HeaderText="Macro Title" ItemStyle-Width="50" />
                                    <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="MacroDescription" HeaderText="Macro Description" ItemStyle-Width="50" />--%>

                                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="50"  HeaderText="Macro Description">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="MacroDescription" runat="server"
                                                Text='<%# Limit(Eval("MacroDescription"),30) %>'
                                                ToolTip='<%# Eval("MacroDescription") %>'
                                               >
                                            </asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PId" HeaderText="PId" ItemStyle-Width="50" Visible="false" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CreatedBy" HeaderText="CreatedBy" ItemStyle-Width="50" />
                                    <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="PId" HeaderText="PId" ItemStyle-Width="50" Visible="false" />--%>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="HId" HeaderText="HId" ItemStyle-Width="50" Visible="false" />


                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ItemStyle-Width="90">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgMacroEdit" ImageUrl="images/edit.png" runat="server" Width="15" Height="15"
                                                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id")+ "," + Eval("FirstName")+ "," + Eval("Hospital")+ "," + Eval("MacroTitle")
                                                             + "," + Eval("macrodescription") +","+Eval("PId")+","+Eval("HId")%>'
                                                OnClick="imgMacroEdit_Click" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to edit this Macro?');" ToolTip="Edit" />


                                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgMacroDelete" ImageUrl="images/Delete.png" runat="server" Width="15" Height="15"
                                                OnClick="imgMacroDelete_Click" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Macro?');"
                                                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id")%>' ToolTip="Delete" />

                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>

                                <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
                                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
                                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
                                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />

                            </asp:GridView>
```

HERE is .CS file code

```
  protected string Limit(object desc, int maxLength)
        {
            var MacroDescription = (string)desc;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(MacroDescription)) { return MacroDescription; }
            return MacroDescription.Length <= maxLength ?
            MacroDescription : MacroDescription.Substring(0, maxLength) + " ... ";
        }
```

Comment: Have a look at https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/278/a-better-way-to-export-gridviews-to-excel#:~:text=There%20are%20countless%20articles%20that%20demonstrate%20exporting%20ASP.NET,an%20HTML%20file%20masquerading%20as%20an%20Excel%20file.

Answer (score 0):

`GridView` with `TemplateField` can be exported easily and also displays properly.
Problem occurs when the GridView with TemplateField Column contains controls like `HyperLink`, `TextBox`, `Button`, `LinkButton`, `RadioButton` or `CheckBox` controls. When such case occurs we need to convert remove these controls and replace them with Label or Literal controls.

> Here is a function of [GetCellText](https://forums.asp.net/t/1893999.aspx?export%20data%20in%20gridview%20to%20CSV).

```
private static string GetCellText(DataControlFieldCell cell)
{
    if (cell.Controls.Count == 0) {
        return CsvFormatted(cell.Text);
    } else {
        foreach (object current_loopVariable in cell.Controls) {
            current = current_loopVariable;
            if (current is Label) {
                return CsvFormatted((current as Label).Text);
            } else if (current is TextBox) {
                return CsvFormatted((current as TextBox).Text);
            } else if (current is LinkButton) {
                return CsvFormatted((current as LinkButton).Text);
            } else if (current is ImageButton) {
                return CsvFormatted((current as ImageButton).AlternateText);
            } else if (current is HyperLink) {
                return CsvFormatted((current as HyperLink).Text);
            } else if (current is DropDownList) {
                return CsvFormatted((current as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Text);
            } else if (current is CheckBox) {
                return CsvFormatted((current as CheckBox).Checked ? "True" : "False");
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```